# Can I run xampp in public?

Tags: xampp

Can I run Xampp in public using a static IP?

I already installed Xampp on Ubuntu 16.04 and it runs well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Incidentally, that also happens to be the answer to the question "Can I drink a glass of gasoline?".

XAMPP is configured in a way that makes it easy to learn PHP. It's not configured properly to run on the internet. The internet is evil and XAMPP is deliberately made insecure so it's easy to use.

If you want a PHP server, don't use XAMPP. It's possible to change its configuration but it's a lot harder than just installing the parts of it you need in their respective default configurations and adapt them very needed.